# How to add data from a service in autocomplete that is inside formsArray?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a formsArray and I want one input field to use Autocomplete. The following example on Stackblitz does exactly except, I want to fetch data from a service then run a loop to extract and put Name attribute of data to an array and then pass that array to options of autocomplete. I have tried doing that in OnInit, constructor but no success.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szxkme?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a mock of service call using rxjs `timer` on `ngOnInit` as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    timer(1000).subscribe(s=>{
      this.options = [{ name: 'Mary' },
          { name: 'Shelley' },
          { name: 'Igor' }]
    })
  }
```

So here instead of `timer.subscribe` you need to replace with service method subscribe.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szxkme-vyst9p?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts